# How to use the value of another key in a sbt task?

Tags: scala, sbt

Say I have defined such a sbt task:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

val mykey = settingKey[Int]("demo key")

mykey := 100

val hello = taskKey[Unit]("demo task")

hello := {println("Hello, world" + mykey)}
```

I have defined a `mykey` whose value is `100`, and I want to use it in another custom task `hello`, but when I run:

```
$ sbt
> hello
```

It outputs:

```
Hello, worldsbt.SettingKey$$anon$4@66db9b08
```

How can I get the value `100` of `mykey`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `value` macro of the Key:

```scala
hello := { println("Hello, world " + mykey.value) }
```

`mykey` is of type `SettingKey[String]` and `value` - is a macro defined in [sbt.std.MacroValue](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.std.MacroValue)

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem.

Comment: the `mkey.value` part?

Comment: Nice to know it uses `macro` to implement it, hard to imagine